# Maven 3.3.1 ECLIPSE: -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, maven

I just installed Maven 3.3.1 on Mac OS X, and building a Maven Project with Eclipse is giving me this error:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.
Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

It did not happen before with Maven 3.2.5.

Is there any way to fix this (except downgrading to 3.2.5) ?

Where exactly can I set this "multiModuleProjectDirectory" property in Eclipse?

Comment: This was a filed m2e bug as of 2015-03-24 , and has since been resolved. Please see stackoverflow.com/a/29735560/751158 .

Answer (score 197, accepted):

In `Eclipse` you need to go like this.

```
Window-> Preference -> Java -> Installed JREs -> Edit
```

In the edit `Default VM arguments` you need to put

If you already set the maven home.

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME
```

Comment: I don't know why, but when you run a maven option like clean in Eclipse it will show that is necessary.

Comment: @atamanroman and all - this was a filed m2e bug as of 2015-03-24 , and has since been resolved.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/29735560/751158 .

Comment: You can also add the VM args from `Run Configuration -> Maven Build`. Select your launch configuration and open the tab `JRE`. Add `-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=$M2_HOME` in VM arguments textbox.

Comment: I followed the solution and still I was seeing the same error.That was because the maven project had reference to jre 1.7 But JAVA_HOME was set to jre1.8.Making Maven project to point to the jre 1.8 in configure Build path->java build path solved the issue.

Answer (score 22):

In IntelliJ you can set this option in VM Options field that you can find in the next configuration view:

*Preferences/Build, execution, deployment/Build tools/Maven/Runner*

[image]

Comment: Also it works for IntelliJ Idea 14.0 with Maven 3.3.9

Answer (score 17):

This was filed as a bug with m2e in Eclipse at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462944 , due to the changes in Maven 3.3.1.

This is fixed in m2e 1.5.2 as of 2015-04-13.  This is an available release that can be installed from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ .

(No more changing JVM arguments for the entire workspace or for specific launch configurations required.)

Comment: I get : 
`An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=epp.package.jee, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.aspectj.runtime.source,1.7.0.20120703164200
No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.contribution.weaving.jdt.source,2.2.0.e37x-RELEASE-20120704-0900
` + others

Comment: The latest 1.5.X release should be here: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.5/

Answer (score 7):

Define like this in the JVM options:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=HOME_PATH_OF_YOU_PROJECT
```

Comment: Where exactly can I set the JVM Options of a Project in Eclipse?

Comment: PROJECT_DIR makes more sense than M2_HOME.

Comment: that variable does not exist - what you actually were trying to refer to is $PROJECT_LOC

Answer (score 4):

In case you have this error message on your commandline, please verify if your PATH variable points to the same maven installation `apache-maven-3.X.X/bin` folder as your M2_HOME variable. In my case I was mixing up two versions which resulted in this error.

Answer (score 3):

go to run configuration, create new `maven build` launch configuration where in the first tab you fill the base directory and the goal,
then, go to `jre tab` and add to the `vm args` this config:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%M2_HOME%
```

where `M2_HOME` is an environment variable pointing to the base directory of your maven installation

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try a second way, you can try to download a path from http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.5/.

Open Help>install new software and download from url above. This way solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue with Maven 3.3 and 3.2 versions, so I decided to downgrade it to version 3.0.5 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

To set the `maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory` property permanently in Maven, I've added a default activated profile which initializes the property with the **MAVEN_HOME** environment variable in the `settings.xml` file.  Or you could also alternatively use the **M2_HOME** environment variable.

```
<profile>
    <id>my-profile</id>
    <properties>
            <maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory>${env.MAVEN_HOME}</maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory>
    </properties>
</profile>
<activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>my-profile</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem with intelliJ 14, i tried out different solutions provided at forums but not worked out. What i did is i completely uninstall intellij and installed intellij 15.0.1 and import the same project then all works fine.