# Running Maven command from Eclipse Kepler giving exception

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am running eclipse command from inside eclipse like Project right click -> Run As -> Maven Clean

I am getting this exception in Eclipse console

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

While i have already setup **M2_HOME** in environment variables

[image]

When i am running Maven from command prompt its working but not from eclipse why?

**Edit:-**

Already disable default Maven and using outside Maven

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It has hapoened to me too, eclipse uses the maven of its own, so you should check the path for maven in eclipse settings! Make sure it is the same as in your environment variable **M2_HOME**

Comment: That i already changed by Windows->Prefrences->Maven->Installation there i already added external Maven

Comment: I cannot remeber the interface, but you might have to disable the previous maven path? Error says there are multiple installations.

Comment: Its already disabled plz check attached screen shot

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but there is another question already answered here;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s