# Maven build issue in eclipse kepler sr2

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am getting following error while running maven install in eclipse

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system propery is not set. Check $M2_HOME environment variable and mvn script match.
```

I configured eclipse to use external maven installation.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its duplicate of

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s)

Issue got resolved.