# Updating m2e version in Eclipse EE?

Tags: java, eclipse, m2e

Is it just me or have they made this absolutely impossible?

On a fresh install of Eclipse Kepler (with m2e 1.4.1) I'm getting a bug with the m2e lifecycle plugin so have decided to do a basic update of the plugin to see if it fixes the issue.

1. I go to update the version via **Help > Check For Updates** and of course it says there are no updates, which isn't true.
2. How about updating manually then. **Help > About Eclipse > Installation Details > Update**  on the plugin itself. Nope, still reports it as up to date, when it's not.
3. OK, how about **Help > Install New Software** then adding the release site : http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/ then **Select All > Next** on 1.8.3 version. Eclipse tells me it can't perform the operation because 1.4.1 is already installed, well duh, I'm trying to update the version, but nope doesn't let me bump up the version, just some weird merge which doesn't fix the issue.
4. OK, now I'm annoyed, how hard should this be? I decide to nuke m2e from the eclipse installation. I go to **Help > Installation Details** select the plugin and uninstall. Then follow the steps above to add back 1.8.3 version from the update site except....nope. 1.4.1 is still installed and I'm not allowed to update it again according to Eclipse.
5. OK, this is getting bad now, I read a few articles online which seem to be in agreement that the only way to make m2e disappear is to delete all references to it from the plugin and features folders. I do this and attempt to reinstall 1.8.3 from the update site. Nope...1.4.1 is still installed according to Eclipse and yet again I can't update. Are you relally telling me I have to start hacking around in the configuration files to delete a plugin?

Has anyone actually been able to successfully do this on Kepler or should I just give up and start using IntelliJ? How such basic things are made so difficult is beyond me, Eclipse's plugin management is horrific.

Comment: Why are you using Eclipse Kepler which is 5 years old? Eclipse Oxygen.3a is the currentversion  and has m2e 1.8.3. You generally can't update a single plugin in an ancient Eclipse

Comment: I confirm this same problem in Eclipse Oxygen. I try to install new software and the installer reports helpfully that it can't install, trying different dependencies, and locks up eclipse for about 10 minutes, only solution is to kill the Eclipse process and restart. Found this trying overcome [this bug in M2E](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s).