# Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set, what?

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven, build

I cloned my colleague's project. I did the build but here is this error immediately:

```
-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory system property is not set.
```

what can i do to solve? thank you, it's very impoprtant.

Comment: Try to check your vm argouments, if you're missing a double quote " or just try to compare your with the working one

Comment: @MatteoZanini italiano? Non me ne intendo di configurazioni, potresti spiegarmi un po' più nel dettaglio cosa fare? grazie mille.
I'm not good at configurations. Can you explain better what to do?

Comment: Can you try some of the solutions proposed here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29330577/maven-3-3-1-eclipse-dmaven-multimoduleprojectdirectory-system-propery-is-not-s

Comment: Take a look at previous answer, check plugin version or if your path has " at the begininng and at the end, if you have space in it. IT: C'è quasi tutto nella risposta precedente, controlla dove hai i VM Argouments se il tuo percorso ha spazi, in quel caso serve un " prima e uno dopo, es. -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\percorso a caso\ diventa -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory="C:\percorso a caso\" e controlla le versioni dei plugin come spiegato nel link precedente

Comment: You are doing something very strange. Calling from plain command line ...?